# fabric how to define complex env.hosts

Tags: python, fabric

i am working on Fabric for my deploying tools and also distribute the command on multiple hosts.
but i don't know how can define a complex hosts in my fabfile.py

for example: i have 4 servers. serverA, serverB, serverC, serverD

```
def prod():
    env.hosts = ["serverA', "serverB" ]

def dev():
    env.hosts = ["serverC' "serverD"]

def all():
    prod()
    dev()
```

is it possible for me to run a command on all hosts without define again?

```
EX: fab all {command}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at defining [roles](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/usage/execution.html#roles) for your environment.

```
from fabric.api import env, run
from fabric.decorators import task

env.roledefs = {
    'prod': ['ServerA', 'ServerB'],
    'dev': ['ServerC', 'ServerD'],
    'envC': ['ServerE', 'ServerF']
}

env.roledefs['all'] = [h for r in env.roledefs.values() for h in r]


@task
def hostname():
    run('hostname -f')
```

This would mean that your will now have to issue your fabric calls like this:

```
fab -R prod hostname
fab -R dev hostname
fab -R all hostname
fab -R dev,envC hostname
```

Comment: It does not work on my side.  here is my fabric version: 
> $ fab -V
> Fabric 1.8.0
> Paramiko 1.12.0
> $ fabb -R all cmd:"ls"

> Fatal error: The following specified roles do not exist:
    all

> Aborting.

Comment: I edited the answer and added the full contents of the fabfile. I tested it with Fabric 1.8.1 and Paramiko 1.12.1.

Comment: Thank you so much because of your kind. i wish can vote you more :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution for something more dynamic... no static config in the fabfile, using bash.

```
mfab() {
    hosts=()
    while [ "$#" != 0 ]; do
        if [ "$1" = -- ]; then
            shift
            break
        fi
        hosts+=("$1")
        shift
    done

    list=$(echo "${hosts[@]}" | tr ' ' ',')
    fab -H "$list" "$@"
}
```

Here's a way to make it do a dry run... run this before your tests:

```
fab() { echo fab "$@"; }
```

example 1: arbitrary size list using shell expansions/globbinb/whatever you want to use

```
mfab node{A..D}{01..05} -- example_command
```

will run a command like:

```
fab -H nodeA01,nodeA02,nodeA03,nodeA04,nodeA05,nodeB01,nodeB02,nodeB03,nodeB04,nodeB05,nodeC01,nodeC02,nodeC03,nodeC04,nodeC05,nodeD01,nodeD02,nodeD03,nodeD04,nodeD05 example_command
```

example 2:  I just deployed 7 new machines and every 2nd one is broken and I want to run a command to check/fix it.

```
mfab node{100..106..2} -- example_command
```

will run a command like:

```
fab -H node100,node102,node104,node106 example_command
```

example 3: more options including `--` used by fabric itself:

```
mfab node{01..10} -- -P -- uname -a
```